# Stop sound playback in C# with SDL library

Tags: c#, audio, sdl, media-player, playback

I have this problem where I can't stop the audio file from playing.

This is a snippet of my code:

```
private Sound bgMusic;
bgMusic = new Sound("bgMusic.wav");

if(gameHasStarted)
    bgMusic.Play();

else
    bgMusic.Stop();
```

I've searched Google mulptiple times, but without any success. The music just doesn't stop. 
I've tried threading this audio file, but without luck.
I've also tried using a MediaPlayer - the sound always plays, whichever option I choose, but it just doesn't stop.

So my question:
How do I stop audio file from playing? Do I need to reset it? Close it? Destroy it? How?!

Answer (score 0):

It's actually not that difficult:

`private System.Media.SoundPlayer playerMainMenu;` - initialize player

`playerMainMenu = new System.Media.SoundPlayer("getlucky.wav");` - load file

`playerMainMenu.PlayLooping();` - to play looping

`playerMainMenu.Play();` - to play once

`playerMainMenu.Stop();` - to stop this player

Works like a charm. Found by trial-and-error.